# grep this, but not this (windows)

Tags: windows, grep

On a windows host I am looking through log files for specific failures.

The string I am looking for is SERV_, but I don't want SERV_SUCCESS or SERV_FAIL. For example, SERV_REPLACE is one of several codes I want to catch.

```
grep SERV *.log -d -n | grep -v SERV_SUCCESS *.log -d -n
```

does not work (returns all lines - everthing matches), but it doesn't complain about syntax either.

All of my topic searches are giving solutions that apply to Linux systems.

Comment: Are you using Powershell on Windows?

Comment: If using Powershell: `sls -path *.log 'SERV_' | sls -NotMatch 'SERV_(FAIL|SUCCESS)`

Comment: How would you add a subfolder search to that command?

Comment: `gci *.log -rec -file | sls 'SERV_' | sls -NotMatch 'SERV_(FAIL|SUCCESS)'`

Comment: magic. I added the trailing single quote and it works perfectly. If you repost as an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following terse syntax would look recursively

- for all `.log` files
- selects the lines containing `SERV_`
- ommits from the results the lines containing `SERV_FAIL` or `SERV_SUCCESS`

`gci *.log -rec -file | sls 'SERV_' | sls -NotMatch 'SERV_(FAIL|SUCCESS)'`

A more readable version would be

```
Get-ChildItem *.log -Recursive -File | 
    Select-String 'SERV_' | 
    Select-String -NotMatch 'SERV_(FAIL|SUCCESS)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Powershell, you can use `Select-String` to achieve what you are looking for. Here is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) for it.

> The Select-String cmdlet searches for text and text patterns in input strings and files. You can use Select-String similar to grep in UNIX or findstr.exe in Windows.

### Usage

```
Select-String
      [-Pattern] <string[]>
      [-Path] <string[]>
      [-SimpleMatch]
      [-CaseSensitive]
      [-Quiet][-List]
      [-Include <string[]>]
      [-Exclude <string[]>]
      [-NotMatch]
      [-AllMatches]
      [-Encoding <Encoding>][-Context <int[]>]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

### Example

```
Get-Command | Out-File -FilePath .\Command.txt
Select-String -Path .\Command.txt -Pattern 'Get', 'Set'  -NotMatch
```